# jquery pqselect plugin not working and no error

Tags: jquery

am at my wits end trying to make this plugin work . jquery pqselect plugin for multiple select box with checkboxes

i have initialized it how they say in the usage but it still doesnt work.

here is my code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="wide" id="id_levels" name="levels">
    <option value="1">Level 1</option>
    <option value="2">Level 2</option>
    <option value="3">Level 3</option>
    <option value="4">Level 4</option>
    <option value="6">Level 6</option>
    <option value="7">Level 7</option>
    <option value="8">Level 8</option>
    <option value="9">Level 9</option>
    <option value="10">Level 10</option></select>
$("#id_levels").pqSelect({
        multiplePlaceholder: "select subject(s)",
        checkbox: true  //adds checkbox to options
    }).pqSelect('open');
```

i hope someone can point out the mistake am making here.

using jquery 1.11.2 core and jquery-ui 1.11.3

Answer (score 0):

Please Put following link and check this is fine for me

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```